What "bait" did they use on the Emperor here?
Chani expresses that she is fighting for her people. Jessica came to wish
her good luck, but Chani notes that Jessica has already won her own battle.
Then the scene changes to Gurney looking through a telescope to
see the Harkonnen army entering the planet Arrakis.

Gurney: He took the bait.
Paul: Oh, the Emperor's very obliging.

What "bait" did they use on the Emperor here?

Paul is the bait. In the source novel we see that he intentionally allows the fact that he's alive and has taken Sardaukar prisoners to become known to the Emperor. He even, quite heavy-handedly, tells the Sardaukar prisoners what to say when they escape captivity, and where to go.

“Well, Captain Aramsham,” Paul said, “the Harkonnens would pay dearly
to learn what you now know. And the Emperor — what he wouldn’t give to
learn an Atreides still lives despite his treachery.”
The captain glanced left and right at the two men remaining to him.
Paul could almost see the thoughts turning over in the man’s head.
Sardaukar did not submit, but the Emperor had to learn of this threat.

and

He looked up at Gurney, who had moved close to listen. “Then we best
kill them,” the lieutenant said.
Paul shook his head, still looking at Gurney. “No. I want them to
escape.” Gurney stared at him.
“Sire . . . ” he breathed.
“Yes?”
“Your man here is right. Kill those prisoners at once. Destroy all
evidence of them. You’ve shamed Imperial Sardaukar! When the Emperor
learns that he’ll not rest until he has you over a slow fire.”

It is intolerable to the Emperor that his men have been captured. If it becomes common knowledge that he supported the Harkonnen in their adventure, it could easily result in outright warfare between him and the Great Houses.
As a result he takes the bait. He comes to Arakeen personally, in order to take over this debacle, fully expecting his legions to make fairly short work of the 'Fremen rabble'.
